# Dish washer drain hose routing

Tags: plumbing, drain, dishwasher

I've installed one dishwasher (from scratch, there wasn't one there before). The dish washer was right next to the kitchen sink and running the drain hose was easy. From the bottom, big loop as high as I could get it and then to the garbage disposal.

Now I'm making a plan to install another dish washer (again from scratch and without one being there before). This time the dishwasher is going to be about 10 feet from the kitchen sink.

My Question:

With this set up what is the best way to run the drain hose?

Run it low all the way and then put in the big loop or run it high all the way and then just connect it to the garbage disposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to make the run as high as possible early on and here's why.

If you mount it low, then the water comes off the pump with a lot of energy, runs along (losing energy) and then has to climb a hill. This means that you have a potential backwash situation and you have a LOT of water sitting in the drain line. I found [this comment from Bosch](http://structuretech1.com/dishwasher-drain/) to be helpful

> The high loop in the drain hose of your dishwasher is to keep water from settling in the hose if it were hanging down any lower or horizontally. This keeps the drain hose dried out and keeps any odors from backing up into the dishwasher.

So I would run the drain line high and then slope it down so can drain and stay empty and dry. The less water you have standing in the line, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I would run up as high under the counter as you can, as steep as you can, and then taper it downhill from there.

That would drain as much water as possible from the pipe after each use.

Good luck!